# Android detect DRM audio content

Tags: android, audio, drm

Is there any possibility in Android 2.1 to detect is audio file DRM-protected?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The platform does not provide any DRM detection utilities. You could POSSIBLY detect it by the fact that playback would fail if you are dealing with an encrypted file, but there would be no way to determine if the problem is encryption or just a bad audio file.